# How to create standalone exe with ActiveX in c++ builder

Tags: c++, windows, resources, c++builder, vlc

In Embarcadero C++Builder, I've created a simple Form using ActiveX Viedo Lan Client component. From [this site](http://bcbjournal.org/articles/vol4/0009/Building_stand-alone_EXEs.htm), I know that you can't unselect "Build with runtime packages", so I'm keeping it checked and "Link with dynamic RTL" unchecked.

Everything works fine on the computer on which I have C++Builder installed, but when I try running it on some other computer I get a "Class not registered" error. `TDUMP -em` shows `kernel32.dll`, `user32.dll`, `oleaut32.dll`, and a lot of repeating `.bpl`'s like `rtl210.bpl`, `vcl210.bpl`, `bcbie210.bpl`, `IndySystem210.bpl`, `IndyProtocols210.bpl` and `IndyCore210.bpl`, bind `comp210.bpl` and `engine210.bpl` and `RESTComponents210.bpl`.

How can I export my program with ActiveX if it can't be linked into application?

Comment: None of those BPLs have anything to do with ActiveX.  But since your app makes use of them, and you enabled Runtime Packages, you must deploy them alongside your EXE. Which BTW, your claim that you cannot unselect "Build with runtime packages" is wrong. If you actually read the article more carefully, it does NOT say that you can't unselect that option in an ActiveX project. It merely says you have to deploy and register any DLLs/OCXs that implement the ActiveX controls you use. That has nothing to do with Runtime Packages.